# how to run the HelloWorld Application on my android device(HTC desire)

Tags: android

When I run the `Hello world` application on my android mobile it shows me this error message

```
Application Hello World(process helloworld.helloworld) has stopped unexpectedly.
```

Note: I've installed the jdk-windows-6 and the android sdk,
then I used mono android in visual studio 2010 for coding the HelloWorld application.
And the hello world application was running correctly on the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the activity to the manifest.xml file.
Please follow [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) before posting this here.